# jQuery $.get is not even firing a request in Internet Explorer, and I'd love to know why

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

**This is not a caching problem,** and the code works fine in all other browsers.

I have a simple $.get request triggered by a button click. With Fiddler open to monitor Internet Explorer 9 HTTP traffic, I can click the button, and I see zero HTTP traffic to www.mydatasource.com on my computer. I've never seen any.

Any idea why I'm not seeing the request go out? Thanks!

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    $.get('http://www.mydatasource.com/', function(data){});
}
```

--------UPDATE-------------

Also have tried a more primal approach (which doesn't work either in Internet Explorer 9):

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    var data = httpGet('http://www.mydatasource.com/');
}

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
   var xmlHttp = null;
   xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
   xmlHttp.send( null );
   return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

In this scenario, you would think you would see request go out on Fiddler, but again, complete silence. **I thought it might be a cross domain problem** but have put everything (web page, script, the "get" url) on the same domain and am still getting no traffic out of Internet Explorer 8. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: @maxenglander Internet Explorer 9 on Windows. Thanks

Comment: How do you know its not a caching problem?

Comment: I suspect it's not a caching problem because I've never seen a request go out. If it was a caching problem, I could reset the browser, restart the computer, and at least see the request go out the first time. As it is, I've never been able to get any $.get request to fire out of IE(I've been monitoring HTTP traffic via Fiddler- so perhaps it's missing the traffic somehow, but I thought it would pick up everything.). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

this is due to the fact that Internet Explorer caches the request and so the request is fired only the first time.

you could use [ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to avoid this

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    $.get('http://www.mydatasource.com/', function(data){});
});
```

in this way a variable that is equal to the current timestamp is sent to the server and the browser doesn't cache the call because a parameter has changed.

You could also do

```
var noCache = new Date().getTime();
$.get('http://www.mydatasource.com/',{nocache: noCache},  function(data){});
```

Comment: Hi Nicola- Thanks for your help. I don't think it's a caching problem. I've never seen the request go out, never, ever, ever. Not even the first time.

Answer (score 0):

It's because IE caching the requests. Add current date stamp at the end of your url. In this case each request will be to unique url:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function () {
    $.get('http://www.mydatasource.com/?' + new Date().getTime(), function(data){});
}
```

Comment: Hi Samich- Thanks for your help. I don't think it's a caching problem. I've never seen the request go out, never, ever, ever. Not even the first time.

Comment: Maybe in your case some another problem, but I faced with it in every project where I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong but are you sure that you wrap your code with in .ready function ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

})
```

Comment: Thanks Bouchaala- I am doing that. I just left it out for simplicity.

Comment: Oki, it just happen sometimes that people forget about it ;)
Did you try a .live('click',function(){}) ?